# interp2 k times

Tags: math, matlab

I have function z(x,y,k) and k is actually my index and I want to interpolate z in a loop

```
for k=1:50
A=interp2(x,y,z(:,:,k),xi,yi)
B(k)=A
end
```

I'm reaaly lost and will be greatfull for any help

Comment: Please provide as many (relevant) details as possible if you want to get a quick and good answer to your problem. What is not working with your code ? What are x,y,xi,yi and B: vectors, matrices (and if so their dimensions) ? Elements of background (why are you doing this) can also help other guiding you toward a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `xi` and `yi` are not scalar, you probably want `B(:,:,k)=A` instead of `B(k)=A`. You can even skip `A` and write

```
for k=1:50
    B(:,:,k) = interp2(x,y,z(:,:,k),xi,yi);
end
```